# Include OR within CASE statement for Column Search Query - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

**The Objective:**

If filterFeatures is equal to "lite" then search for this:

```
FeatureString LIKE '%" + lite + @"%' OR FeatureString LIKE '%" + bronze + @"%'
```

Or, if filterFeatures is equal to "professional" then search for this:

```
FeatureString LIKE '%" + professional + @"%' OR FeatureString LIKE '%" + gold + @"%'
```

---

My idea was to use a CASE statement, but there might be a better solution?

`FeatureString` is the column name.

`filterFeatures` is the string that is being searched for in the FeatureString column.

`'%" + bronze + @"%'`, `'%" + lite+ @"%'`, `'%" + professional+ @"%'` are defined strings.

If i take the `OR` statements out then it works. But the goal is to search for two parameters if "filterfeatures" is equal to `lite` or `professional`.

---

**Current Query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM[database]  
WHERE
(
(FeatureString LIKE
CASE '%" + filterFeatures + @"%'
WHEN 
('%" + lite + @"%')
THEN 
('%" + lite + @"%' OR FeatureString LIKE '%" + bronze + @"%')
WHEN 
('%" + professional + @"%')
THEN 
('%" + professional + @"%' OR FeatureString LIKE '%" + gold + @"%')
ELSE
('%" + filterFeatures + @"%')
END)
)
```

**Error Message:**

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'.

Please let me know if the question needs to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Your `CASE` expression looks wrong. If the filter term is passed as parameter; say `@filter` then it should look like

```
CASE WHEN @filter = 'lite' THEN FeatureString LIKE '%lite%'
```

Comment: can you make it work with an OR statement? Because we need to search for two.THEN FeatureString LIKE '%lite%'  OR  FeatureString LIKE '%bronze%'

Answer (score 1):

You can't structure your CASE like this when you implement compound conditions.  And you can **NEVER** put conditions in the `THEN` clause.  You need to write the full condition after each WHEN.

In other words you can't do this:

```
CASE @a
  WHEN @b or @c THEN ...
```

Instead you have to do this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN @a=@b OR @a=@c THEN ...
```

In your case, you're actually looking for logic like this:

```
WHERE (@a='foo' AND (@b LIKE 'bar' OR @b LIKE 'bur'))
OR ...
```

You don't even need a CASE expression at all.

Comment: I dont see how this works. If featurestring is lite then the sql needs to search for lite OR FeatureString LIKE bronze. On the other hand, if featurestring is professional then sql needs to search for professional and gold.

Comment: Re-read the first paragraph in your question ("The Objective").  Look at my last logic example.   Supply "filterFeature" in place of `@a`, and supply "FeatureString" in place of `@b`, and it's exactly the logic you say you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works, but it isn't very elegant.

```
SELECT *
FROM[database]  
WHERE
((FeatureString LIKE 
                                (CASE '%" + filterFeatures + @"%'
                                    WHEN 
                                        ('%" + lite + @"%')
                                    THEN 
                                        ('%" + lite + @"%')
                                    WHEN 
                                        ('%" + professional + @"%')
                                    THEN 
                                        ('%" + professional + @"%')
                                    ELSE
                                        ('%" + filterFeatures + @"%')
                                END)
                                OR FeatureString LIKE 
                                (CASE '%" + filterFeatures + @"%'
                                    WHEN 
                                        ('%" + lite + @"%')
                                    THEN 
                                        ('%" + bronze + @"%')
                                    WHEN 
                                        ('%" + professional + @"%')
                                    THEN 
                                        ('%" + gold + @"%')
                                    ELSE
                                        ('%" + filterFeatures + @"%')
                                END))
)
```